# ROS Answers SE migration: about SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to know if there is any official websites about SLAM,except for the OpenSLAM.org.
The following is my assumption：If I want to check whether the gmapping package  I downloaded is opensource or not,I may write a program with calling the gmapping package under ubuntu, if my program runs successfully,it proves the package is opensource.But now I don't know how to call it,is there any file telling me how to do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151931/about-slam/) by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Code is open source if the code is available (online) under some open source license. This is true for all approaches on OpenSlam.org. If you manage to compile and run it tells you something about the ease of use of the approach and your skills in compiling other people´s software, but really doesn´t have anything to do with "proving" the approach is open source or not.

That being said, some compilation instructions can be found [here](https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/gmapping/trunk/docs/Instructions.txt), but I´m not sure if those work out of the box. You might have to read up on how Makefiles work if you want to compile gmapping yourself. Note that this question really goes beyond the scope of this site though, because ROS Answers is about ROS related answers (and compiling gmapping standalone has nothing to do with ROS).

You´ll find some SLAM approaches for ROS that are not uploaded to OpenSlam.org, but the latter definitely is the largest collection of SLAM approaches on the net I think.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [danmianjing_00](https://answers.ros.org/users/14196/danmianjing_00/) on 2014-04-11**:
thank you！